# Hangs on file upload

Tags: ssh.net

My client code looks like this...

```
public void Upload(string localFile, string remoteFile)
{
                ConnectionInfo connectionInfo =
                    new PasswordConnectionInfo(hostIP, username, password);

                using (ScpClient scpClient = new ScpClient(connectionInfo))
                {
                    scpClient.Connect();

                    FileInfo localFileInfo = new FileInfo(localFile);

                    scpClient.Upload(localFileInfo, remoteFile);

                    scpClient.Disconnect();
                }
}
```

When calling this code the library hangs on the call to Monitor in the following...

```
        while (!this.ReadAvailable(count))
            Monitor.Wait(this._buffer);
```

This snippet is from `int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)` in `PipeStream`.

Others seemed to have had similar issues [here](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/discussions/347373).

But the responses haven't helped me as yet and I'd like to avoid editing the source code.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am having similar issues with the SftpClient, but only on one server. It works on another local server, so I suspect it's a server configuration problem. Did you manage to resolve this somehow?

Comment: No I was lucky and got to use FTP.